# Как выровнять текст в зависимости от количества строк?

Tags: html, css

столкнулся с проблемой, не знаю как выровнять текст по отношению к иконке в зависимости от количества строк.

1. Если в одну строку, то текст выравнивается относительно иконки по центру
2. Если в две и более строк, то текст выравнивается относительно иконки по верхнему краю

```css
.wrapper1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.text {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.wrapper2 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="icon-wrapper">
    <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M20 4H4C3.44771 4 3 4.44772 3 5V19C3 19.5523 3.44772 20 4 20H20C20.5523 20 21 19.5523 21 19V5C21 4.44771 20.5523 4 20 4ZM4 2C2.34315 2 1 3.34315 1 5V19C1 20.6569 2.34315 22 4 22H20C21.6569 22 23 20.6569 23 19V5C23 3.34315 21.6569 2 20 2H4ZM6 7H8V9H6V7ZM11 7C10.4477 7 10 7.44772 10 8C10 8.55228 10.4477 9 11 9H17C17.5523 9 18 8.55228 18 8C18 7.44772 17.5523 7 17 7H11ZM8 11H6V13H8V11ZM10 12C10 11.4477 10.4477 11 11 11H17C17.5523 11 18 11.4477 18 12C18 12.5523 17.5523 13 17 13H11C10.4477 13 10 12.5523 10 12ZM8 15H6V17H8V15ZM10 16C10 15.4477 10.4477 15 11 15H17C17.5523 15 18 15.4477 18 16C18 16.5523 17.5523 17 17 17H11C10.4477 17 10 16.5523 10 16Z" fill="currentColor" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <span class="text">
    Какой то текст в одну строку
  </span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="icon-wrapper">
    <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M20 4H4C3.44771 4 3 4.44772 3 5V19C3 19.5523 3.44772 20 4 20H20C20.5523 20 21 19.5523 21 19V5C21 4.44771 20.5523 4 20 4ZM4 2C2.34315 2 1 3.34315 1 5V19C1 20.6569 2.34315 22 4 22H20C21.6569 22 23 20.6569 23 19V5C23 3.34315 21.6569 2 20 2H4ZM6 7H8V9H6V7ZM11 7C10.4477 7 10 7.44772 10 8C10 8.55228 10.4477 9 11 9H17C17.5523 9 18 8.55228 18 8C18 7.44772 17.5523 7 17 7H11ZM8 11H6V13H8V11ZM10 12C10 11.4477 10.4477 11 11 11H17C17.5523 11 18 11.4477 18 12C18 12.5523 17.5523 13 17 13H11C10.4477 13 10 12.5523 10 12ZM8 15H6V17H8V15ZM10 16C10 15.4477 10.4477 15 11 15H17C17.5523 15 18 15.4477 18 16C18 16.5523 17.5523 17 17 17H11C10.4477 17 10 16.5523 10 16Z" fill="currentColor" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <span class="text">
    Какой то текст в
    <br>
    две строки строку
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: может и саму иконку и текст выравнивать по центру по вертикали раз вы flex используете

Comment: Почему у Вас в первом случае align-items: center, а во втором - align-items: flex-start? Сделайте всем align-items: center, и будет выравнивание по центру

Comment: @humster_spb требования дизайнера я написал в 1 и 2 пунктах

Comment: скажите дизайнеру, чтобы не занимался ерундой: если строки добавляются динамически, и Вы заранее не знаете, будет она одна или их будет несколько, на чистом css Вы эту задачу не решите: придётся использовать js, проверять высоту блока с текстом и в зависимости от результата делать выравнивание

Comment: а если к этому добавить адаптацию под мобильные устройства, когда на десктопе у Вас одна строка, а на мобильном она же превращается в 2-3, это ещё немного геморроя в Вашу копилку

Comment: @humster_spb: _"... скажите дизайнеру"_ Думаю, что тут не к дизайнеру вопросы. Он - художник, он так видит. Скорее, это проблема фронтА. А уж почему фронт против JS, это не должно напрягать ни дизайнера, ни заказчика. И не обязательно согласовывать такие вещи с ними.

Comment: @UModeL , js - он всё-таки для некоего функционала. А делать выравнивание с его помощью только потому, что так захотелось дизайнеру, - ну, такое

Comment: @humster_spb: фронт должен внимательно рассмотреть задание и понимать, за что берётся, чтобы не метаться в поисках костылей. А вот, если в процессе начнут выдумывать, то можно посылать на разное количество букв, в зависимости от извращённых фантазий вопрошающих :)

Comment: пока внимательно коменты не прочитал, думал что в п 1 и 2 описан косяк, который надо исправить, а в итоге оказалось что это такая задумка, я в ступоре)))

Answer (score 0):

Вот Вам пример решения с помощью jQuery. Но лучше убедите дизайнера, что так делать не надо:

```js
$('.wrapper').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('.text').outerHeight() <= 16) {
    $(this).css('align-items','center');
  }
})

$(window).on('resize orientationchange',function(){
    $('.wrapper').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('.text').outerHeight() <= 16) {
      $(this).css('align-items','center');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
}

.text {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="icon-wrapper">
    <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M20 4H4C3.44771 4 3 4.44772 3 5V19C3 19.5523 3.44772 20 4 20H20C20.5523 20 21 19.5523 21 19V5C21 4.44771 20.5523 4 20 4ZM4 2C2.34315 2 1 3.34315 1 5V19C1 20.6569 2.34315 22 4 22H20C21.6569 22 23 20.6569 23 19V5C23 3.34315 21.6569 2 20 2H4ZM6 7H8V9H6V7ZM11 7C10.4477 7 10 7.44772 10 8C10 8.55228 10.4477 9 11 9H17C17.5523 9 18 8.55228 18 8C18 7.44772 17.5523 7 17 7H11ZM8 11H6V13H8V11ZM10 12C10 11.4477 10.4477 11 11 11H17C17.5523 11 18 11.4477 18 12C18 12.5523 17.5523 13 17 13H11C10.4477 13 10 12.5523 10 12ZM8 15H6V17H8V15ZM10 16C10 15.4477 10.4477 15 11 15H17C17.5523 15 18 15.4477 18 16C18 16.5523 17.5523 17 17 17H11C10.4477 17 10 16.5523 10 16Z" fill="currentColor" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <span class="text">
    Какой то текст в одну строку
  </span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="icon-wrapper">
    <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M20 4H4C3.44771 4 3 4.44772 3 5V19C3 19.5523 3.44772 20 4 20H20C20.5523 20 21 19.5523 21 19V5C21 4.44771 20.5523 4 20 4ZM4 2C2.34315 2 1 3.34315 1 5V19C1 20.6569 2.34315 22 4 22H20C21.6569 22 23 20.6569 23 19V5C23 3.34315 21.6569 2 20 2H4ZM6 7H8V9H6V7ZM11 7C10.4477 7 10 7.44772 10 8C10 8.55228 10.4477 9 11 9H17C17.5523 9 18 8.55228 18 8C18 7.44772 17.5523 7 17 7H11ZM8 11H6V13H8V11ZM10 12C10 11.4477 10.4477 11 11 11H17C17.5523 11 18 11.4477 18 12C18 12.5523 17.5523 13 17 13H11C10.4477 13 10 12.5523 10 12ZM8 15H6V17H8V15ZM10 16C10 15.4477 10.4477 15 11 15H17C17.5523 15 18 15.4477 18 16C18 16.5523 17.5523 17 17 17H11C10.4477 17 10 16.5523 10 16Z" fill="currentColor" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <span class="text">
    Какой то текст в
    <br>
    две строки
  </span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="icon-wrapper">
    <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M20 4H4C3.44771 4 3 4.44772 3 5V19C3 19.5523 3.44772 20 4 20H20C20.5523 20 21 19.5523 21 19V5C21 4.44771 20.5523 4 20 4ZM4 2C2.34315 2 1 3.34315 1 5V19C1 20.6569 2.34315 22 4 22H20C21.6569 22 23 20.6569 23 19V5C23 3.34315 21.6569 2 20 2H4ZM6 7H8V9H6V7ZM11 7C10.4477 7 10 7.44772 10 8C10 8.55228 10.4477 9 11 9H17C17.5523 9 18 8.55228 18 8C18 7.44772 17.5523 7 17 7H11ZM8 11H6V13H8V11ZM10 12C10 11.4477 10.4477 11 11 11H17C17.5523 11 18 11.4477 18 12C18 12.5523 17.5523 13 17 13H11C10.4477 13 10 12.5523 10 12ZM8 15H6V17H8V15ZM10 16C10 15.4477 10.4477 15 11 15H17C17.5523 15 18 15.4477 18 16C18 16.5523 17.5523 17 17 17H11C10.4477 17 10 16.5523 10 16Z" fill="currentColor" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <span class="text">
    Какой то текст в
    <br>
    три <br> строки
  </span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="icon-wrapper">
    <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M20 4H4C3.44771 4 3 4.44772 3 5V19C3 19.5523 3.44772 20 4 20H20C20.5523 20 21 19.5523 21 19V5C21 4.44771 20.5523 4 20 4ZM4 2C2.34315 2 1 3.34315 1 5V19C1 20.6569 2.34315 22 4 22H20C21.6569 22 23 20.6569 23 19V5C23 3.34315 21.6569 2 20 2H4ZM6 7H8V9H6V7ZM11 7C10.4477 7 10 7.44772 10 8C10 8.55228 10.4477 9 11 9H17C17.5523 9 18 8.55228 18 8C18 7.44772 17.5523 7 17 7H11ZM8 11H6V13H8V11ZM10 12C10 11.4477 10.4477 11 11 11H17C17.5523 11 18 11.4477 18 12C18 12.5523 17.5523 13 17 13H11C10.4477 13 10 12.5523 10 12ZM8 15H6V17H8V15ZM10 16C10 15.4477 10.4477 15 11 15H17C17.5523 15 18 15.4477 18 16C18 16.5523 17.5523 17 17 17H11C10.4477 17 10 16.5523 10 16Z" fill="currentColor" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <span class="text">
    Какой то текст снова в одну строку
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Заменить `align-items: flex-start;` на `align-items: center;`

```
.wrapper2 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  line-height: 0;
}
```